# Am I able to create an SSO that uses firebase as the idP for my Shopify store?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, shopify, shopify-app

How can I use firebase as an idP when authenticating customers logging into a Shopify store.

I want users to sign up on my web app for an account.

Then when they make it to my Shopify store for them to have an option to sign into the store using my web app credentials.
Similar to how you can add a 'sign in with Google' option.

How do I create that SSO using Shopify as the service provider and firebase as the idP so that my users on my web app can also sign into my Shopify app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very good question.

Once connected with firebase you have to add a token (http header authorization) to each request to shopify API.

You have to find a way to set the public key of your firebase project on your shopify server.

That permit shopify server to decode and use the firebase token

Shopify should have an API documentation to exhange public/private key with another auth provider. (firebase auth, [auth0](https://auth0.com/fr))

Answer (score 2):

Note that SSO only works if your Shopify store is on the Plus plan. Any other attempts to do SSO with Shopify will almost certainly fail, so just to save you the time and effort in case you missed that memo.

Comment: I had seen that somewhere, it's called Multipass? My issue is that there are Shopify apps that provide SSO for Shopify without the need of Plus. I'm wandering how they've achieved this. Also I see that miniOrange has an api and not just an app. would there be any way to leverage this to achieve my goal?

Comment: You may think these Apps provide SSO Multipass without the shops being on Plus but I am pretty sure you'd be mistaken. I am not saying they are not doing something, but they are not doing Multipass, that is for sure. They are doing bullshit of some kind, and it probably makes it seem like it is all working.

Comment: Curious. miniOrange seem to claim they provide SSO without the need of Plus. Would it be possible to create a login button that gets a user to authenticate with my firebase project like a normal web app and then use those credentials to create a customer account on the Shopify store in the background? sort of create an illusion of SSO and then they can use the token gained from firebase to get access to their user data on my Firestore? Maybe that's a little too convoluted and potentially insecure.

Comment: As I said, miniOrange (et al)  indeed do Wizard of Oz stuff to fake it. Anyone can try and fake it. If you make it, and you fake it, you win! If you make it, and the fake is no good, you lose.